# I need to send a message to the person resposible for a specific wallet

Tags: transactions, message

Using Multibit, we sent btc to an incorrect wallet address. We have sent a small amount of BTC to this address before, so it is listed in our wallet's Transaction list, but is unfortunately not associated with any recipient information. The blockchain record of that original transaction is accessible.

Question is, is there any way to send a **pure message** to the address, to see if they have a record of he more recent incorrect transfer. After that, it's in the lap of the gods!  If recipient is identifiable and honorable, he would respond favorably to our request for return.  If not, we fully understand that the funds are lost.

Comment: http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/7667/is-it-possible-to-send-a-message-to-a-bitcoin-address-how?rq=1